# How to handle reoccurring calendar events and tasks (SQL Server tables & C#)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I need to scheduled events, tasks, appointments, etc. in my DB.  Some of them will be one time  appointments, and some will be reoccurring "To-Dos" which must be checked off.  After looking a google's calendar layout and others, plus doing a lot of reading here is what I have so far.

Calendar table (Could be called schedule table I guess):  Basic_Event Title, start/end, reoccurs info.

Calendar occurrence table:  ties to schedule table, occurrence specific text, next occurrence date / time????

Looked here at how SQL Server does its jobs:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178644.aspx
  but this is slightly different.

Why two tables:  I need to track status of each instance of the reoccurring task.  Otherwise this would be much simpler...

so... on to the questions:

1)  Does this seem like the proper way to go about it?  Is there a better way to handle the multiple occurrence issue?
2)  How often / how should I trigger creation of the occurrences?  I really don't want to create a bunch of occurrences... BUT... What if the user wants to view next year's calendar...

Comment: any final solution with full source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Makes sense to have your schedule definition for a task in one table and then a separate table to record each instance of that separately - that's the approach I've taken in the past.

And with regards to creating the occurrences, there's probably no need to create them all up front. Especially when you consider tasks that repeat indefinitely! Again, the approach I've used in the past is to only create the next occurrence. When that instance is actioned, the next instance is then calculated and created.

This leaves the issue of viewing future occurrences. For this, you can start of with the initial/next scheduled occurrence and just calculate the future occurrences on-the-fly at display time.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I like the thought of only creating the next occurrence and then calculating the rest on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't an exact answer to your question I've solved this problem before in SQL Server (though database here is irrelevant) by modeling a solution based on [Unix's cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Instead of string parsing we used integer columns in a table to store the various time units.

We had events which could be scheduled; they could either point to a one-time schedule table that represented a distinct point in time (a date/time) or to the recurring schedule table which is modelled after cron.

Additionally remember to model your solution correctly.  An event has a duration but the duration is unrelated to the schedule (but an event's duration may impact the schedule by causing conflicts).  Do not try to model duration as part of your schedule.

Answer (score 0):

In the past when we've done this, we had 2 tables:

1) Schedules -> Includes recurrence information

2) Exceptions -> Edit/changes to specific instances

Using SQL, it's possible to get the list of "Schedules" that have at least one instance in a given date range. Then you can expand in the GUI where each instance lies.